Oracle apex DA call porcesses with delays
I two processes that call different API endpoints, and I would like to have an delay inbetween them or have one process call the other process.
Can't seem to figure it out.
I thought that usign a DA would be the best option , something like this.
apex.server.process("my_process", {
  success: function(data) {
    apex.message.showPageSuccess("Process completed successfully.");
  },
  error: function(data) {
    apex.message.showPageError("Error occurred: " + data.message);
  }
});

But thats not working.
Thanks for any help.

You could use the type "Debounce" in the dynamic actions. That allows you specify a delay for a dynamic action

However, if the endpoints are called using pl/sql it might make more sense to just execute the 2 procedures one after the other using pl/sql instead of with 2 different dynamic actions. With dynamic actions there is always the chance of one process taking too long and not being finished when the other starts.

right now the endpoints are called with a button click.  And I have two different process one to send a command and the other to retrieve a value.  I need the first process to trigger then wait 5 seconds and trigger the second process.

JavaScript or pl/sql ?

I've tried two options and both dont work, one is on submit page, and the second is via DA and JS code.

How is the rest call done ? JavaScript or pl/sql ? Pls share that code. Pls explain in detail what is done and how. Now it’s all vague
